# How do I know which Python install is being used?

Tags: macos, python

If I type the command `which python`, then I get:

```
Oliviers-iMac:~$ which -a python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

If I then type `python --version`, how do I know which Python install I'm getting the version of? Are the two locations above 2 different Python installs?

Comment: `which python` i.e. without the -a tells you which one will be used

Comment: I suppose which one gets executed depends on the order in $PATH, right?

Comment: @Oliver yes correct

Answer (score 1):

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` is most likely a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink).

`readlink` on a simlink will give you the target.

For example on my Mavericks installation I have following :

```
$readlink /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python2
$readlink /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
python2.7
```

Which means when I run `python` it actually runs `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

---

Also there is something funny, when running `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

Try this

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.executable
```

Which will return this :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOs/Python
```

Comment: Strange! I wonder why intermediary simlinks are required? Maybe it's because python 2.7 extends python 2 which extends python?

Comment: By the way, when you say that /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python is most likely a simlink, do you mean that it points to /usr/bin/python? DO simlinks always point to binaries in /usr/bin? (Sorry for the noob questions!)

Comment: symlink can point to anything anywere. File, directory, binary. There (a bit) like aliases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding in python, you may wanna:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

The path would probably show you which version of python you are using.