# Full path to python as reported by ps

Tags: bash, python, path

When I run python from the shell I for example do `python2.7 script`.

I later need to find this command again based on the `ps aux` output, however this output shows a full absolute path like this:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

I am unsure how I can resolve `python2.7` to the path above. I tried to install realpath (brew install coreutils), and ran `` realpath `which python2.7` ``, however that is not giving the exact same path, it gives:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

I also tried `python -c "import os; print os.path.realpath('/usr/bin/python2.7')"` but that gives the same different path.

Why the difference and is there any way I can resolve to the other path ?

Comment: How is the app started?

Comment: @Mark From the commandline using the command I listed above: `python2.7 script` where script can be any python script. (Actually the same problem exist if I just start the python interpreter using `python2.7`)

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want  ?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I was hoping there was some non python specific solution though for going from an executable to the correct full absolute path. But your answer will probably solve my immediate issue.

Comment: I came across the same "problem" few days back on another question : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125825/how-do-i-know-which-python-install-is-being-used/125829#125829 I still didn't find what exactly happens.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler no you issue is different - yours is a simple one of which is the first executable on the path - this is more complex as there is something internal to python

Comment: I was talking about the "funny part", a the bottom of my answer.